# Mysterious `natbib` error on citations involving math mode: `not loaded` in .bbl file

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to cite the following four papers that use math mode in their titles:

```
@article{ma-20arXiv2012.00940,
  author =       {Gaoting Lin and Jaehong Jeong and Chaebin Kim and Yao Wang and Qing Huang and Takatsugu Masuda and Shinichiro Asai and Shinichi Itoh and Gerrit G\"unther and Margarita Russina and Zhilun Lu and Jieming Sheng and Le Wang and Jiucai Wang and Guohua Wang and Qingyong Ren and Chuanying Xi and Wei Tong and Langsheng Ling and Zhengxin Liu and Liusuo Wu and Jiawei Mei and Zhe Qu and Haidong Zhou and Je-Geun Park and Yuan Wan and Jie Ma},
  title =        {Field-induced quantum spin disordered state in spin-1/2 honeycomb magnet {Na$_2$Co$_2$TeO$_6$} with small {K}itaev interaction},
        language = {en},
        number = {1},
        urldate = {2021-10-02},
        journal = {Nature Communications},
        month = sep,
        year = {2021},
        pages = {5559},
}

@article{wong_zig-zag_2016,
  author =       {Wong, Cheryl and Avdeev, Maxim and Ling, Chris D.},
  title =        {Zig-zag magnetic ordering in honeycomb-layered {Na$_3$Co$_2$SbO$_6$}},
  journal =      {J. Solid State Chem.},
  year =         {2016},
  OPTkey =       {},
  volume =       {243},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  pages =        {18},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022459616302997},
  doi = {10.1016/j.jssc.2016.07.032},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}

@article{bera_zigzag_2017,
  title = {Zigzag antiferromagnetic ground state with anisotropic correlation lengths in the 
           quasi-two-dimensional honeycomb lattice compound                                                                         
           $\mathrm{Na}_{2}\mathrm{Co}_{2}\mathrm{TeO}_{6}$}, 
  author = {Bera, A. K. and Yusuf, S. M. and Kumar, Amit and Ritter, C.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {95},
  issue = {9},
  pages = {094424},
  numpages = {12},
  year = {2017},
  month = {Mar},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.95.094424},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.95.094424}
}

@article{lefrancois_magnetic_2016,
  title = {Magnetic properties of the honeycomb oxide $\mathrm{Na}_{2}\mathrm{Co}_{2}\mathrm{TeO}_{6}$},                                                      
  author = {Lefran\ifmmode \mbox{\c{c}}\else \c{c}\fi{}ois, E. and Songvilay, M. and Robert, J. and Nataf, G. and Jordan, E. and Chaix, L. and Colin, C. V. and Lejay, P. and Hadj-Azzem, A. and Ballou, R. and Simonet, V.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {94},
  issue = {21},
  pages = {214416},
  numpages = {9},
  year = {2016},
  month = {Dec},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.94.214416},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.214416}
}
```

in a document using `revtex`, with the preamble

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress,longbibliography,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prx,notitlepage,twocolumn,floatfix]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\cite{bera_zigzag_2017, wong_zigzag_2016, lefrancois_magnetic_2016}
\cite{ma-20arXiv2012.00940}
\bibliography{cobaltates}
\end{document}
```

For reasons I cannot fathom, after compiling with `latexmake` any citations of the `wong` paper do not render ,while the others work fine. Perplexingly, the error message points to a totally different line in the `.bbl` file,

```
{{\selectlanguage {en}\enquote {\bibinfo {title} {Field-induced quantum spin
  disordered state in spin-1/2 honeycomb magnet {Na$_2$Co$_2$TeO$_6$} with
  small {K}itaev interaction},}\ }}
```

claiming that something is 'not loaded'. (?) This is especially strange given that citations of the 'field-induced' paper render correctly.
What is happening, and how many goats do I need to sacrifice to appease the bibtex gods?

p.s. I've been sure to clear all of the build files between runs.

Comment: Have you tried loading a package such as `mhchem` and replacing `{Na$_2$Co$_2$TeO$_6$}` with `{\ce{Na2Co2TeO6}}`, and likewise for the other chemical formulas. Also, `Lefran\ifmmode \mbox{\c{c}}\else \c{c}\fi{}ois` looks **utterly specious** to me, as it's a word that should *never* occur in math mode to begin with. Why not just write `Lefran{\c c}ois`?

Comment: As it turns out, this particular issue was nothing to do with the math in the title (just 'natbib' disliking the language and month fields, as Mensch said). 
Thanks for the pickup on Lefrancois, this bibliography was automatically generated by Zotero and its opinions on formatting are... interesting

Comment: Please be more careful with how you quote from @Mensch's answer. To be sure, the answer says *nothing* about `natbib` "liking" or "disliking" anything. `natbib` is primarily a citation management package. (Secondarily, it provides a few bibliography styles, such as `plainnat` and `unsrtnat`.) As such, `natbib` does *not* process the `language` and `month` fields. That's done by BibTeX, which takes its cues from the bibliography style in use. Maybe the `revtex` class employs a bib style that's not programmed to recognize the string variables `sep`, `mar`, etc. Most other bib styles do, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: The usend language `en` with

```
language = {en},
```

in your bib file is unknown, in the following MWE I simply deleted that line.

Second: I changed line

```
    month = sep,
```

to the line

```
    month = {Sep},
```

to get a known month name.

With this changes in the bib file you get the following MWE (I added the bib file with package `filecontents`, and used class `revtex4-2` instead outdated `revtex4-1`):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ma-20arXiv2012.00940,
  author =       {Gaoting Lin and Jaehong Jeong and Chaebin Kim and Yao Wang and Qing Huang and Takatsugu Masuda and Shinichiro Asai and Shinichi Itoh and Gerrit G\"unther and Margarita Russina and Zhilun Lu and Jieming Sheng and Le Wang and Jiucai Wang and Guohua Wang and Qingyong Ren and Chuanying Xi and Wei Tong and Langsheng Ling and Zhengxin Liu and Liusuo Wu and Jiawei Mei and Zhe Qu and Haidong Zhou and Je-Geun Park and Yuan Wan and Jie Ma},
  title =        {Field-induced quantum spin disordered state in spin-1/2 honeycomb magnet {Na$_2$Co$_2$TeO$_6$} with small {K}itaev interaction},
        number = {1},
        urldate = {2021-10-02},
        journal = {Nature Communications},
        month = {Sep},
        year = {2021},
        pages = {5559},
}

@article{wong_zig-zag_2016,
  author =       {Wong, Cheryl and Avdeev, Maxim and Ling, Chris D.},
  title =        {Zig-zag magnetic ordering in honeycomb-layered {Na$_3$Co$_2$SbO$_6$}},
  journal =      {J. Solid State Chem.},
  year =         {2016},
  OPTkey =       {},
  volume =       {243},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  pages =        {18},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022459616302997},
  doi = {10.1016/j.jssc.2016.07.032},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}

@article{bera_zigzag_2017,
  title = {Zigzag antiferromagnetic ground state with anisotropic correlation lengths in the 
           quasi-two-dimensional honeycomb lattice compound                                                                         
           $\mathrm{Na}_{2}\mathrm{Co}_{2}\mathrm{TeO}_{6}$}, 
  author = {Bera, A. K. and Yusuf, S. M. and Kumar, Amit and Ritter, C.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {95},
  issue = {9},
  pages = {094424},
  numpages = {12},
  year = {2017},
  month = {Mar},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.95.094424},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.95.094424}
}

@article{lefrancois_magnetic_2016,
  title = {Magnetic properties of the honeycomb oxide $\mathrm{Na}_{2}\mathrm{Co}_{2}\mathrm{TeO}_{6}$},                                                      
  author = {Lefran\ifmmode \mbox{\c{c}}\else \c{c}\fi{}ois, E. and Songvilay, M. and Robert, J. and Nataf, G. and Jordan, E. and Chaix, L. and Colin, C. V. and Lejay, P. and Hadj-Azzem, A. and Ballou, R. and Simonet, V.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {94},
  issue = {21},
  pages = {214416},
  numpages = {9},
  year = {2016},
  month = {Dec},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.94.214416},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.214416}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[%
  superscriptaddress,longbibliography,amsmath,amssymb,
  aps,prx,notitlepage,twocolumn,floatfix
]{revtex4-2} % revtex4-1

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\cite{bera_zigzag_2017, wong_zig-zag_2016, lefrancois_magnetic_2016}
\cite{ma-20arXiv2012.00940}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: @Mico I changed the code, thanks!